# Delphi Windows Service as Scheduler for run Jobs under multiple User (Server or Saas)

Tags: windows, authentication, delphi, server, service

I've written a service in Delphi that is a simple scheduler for jobs, for example running a query or running a UI software or checking for freezes, etc.

Everything works on a single PC, but I need to install the service on a server and manage all users that are logged in.
There are jobs that can run for all users, but others that can not run for some users and run for other users.

I've tried `GetUserName()` and other stuff I found here, but when I try to get the current user for the service I get `SYSTEM`. I read that for services installed as Admin, this is correct, but how can I get the logged in user and be sure to run the job for the correct user?

Comment: There's a fundamental difference between users being _logged_ and users being _logged **in**_.

Comment: This is a software design question.

Answer (score 1):

A service and each logged-in user run in separate terminal sessions. `GetUserName()`  gets the username of the session it is called in. That is why you are seeing `SYSTEM` when called in the service session.

The service can use the [WTS API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/) to enumerate active user sessions ([`WTSEnumerateSessions()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsenumeratesessionsw)) and get information from them ([`WTSQuerySessionInformation()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsquerysessioninformationw)), such as their usernames.

To run an external process in a specific user session, the service can use [`WTSQueryUserToken()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsqueryusertoken) to get the session's user token, and then [`CreateProcessAsUser()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasuserw) to run the process as that user.